# Bootstrap Popup with Dynamic Width as per content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created bootstrap modal, and appending some html through AJAX...

I am not able to show perfect width as per content. I have tried:

```
width: 'auto'; //it looks as in Screenshot
width: 100%;   //it takes whole page width
```

It looks like:

[image: image1]

```js
var PopupHelper = {
  Show: function () {
    $("#popup_content").empty();
    var qAjax = new AjaxHelper("/Services/Service.asmx/GetCurrentPopupContent");
    qAjax.OnSuccess = function (data) {
      $("#popup_content").html(data);
      $('#popup-Model').css({ 'width' : 'auto','overflow': 'auto' });
      $("#popup-Model").modal();
    }
    qAjax.Init();
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Popup Window -->
<div class="modal fade" id="popup-Model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:-10px !important">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="popup_content">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!--Popup Window -->
```

How to make modal width, as per the content inside `modal-body`?

> NOTE: modal HTML shown in image can vary

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using javascript to render this modal, it will be easier to just set the `modal-dialog` width to the same width as your content. It's hard to do this only with CSS because `modal-dialog` have fixed width (varying per screen size).

```
$("#popup_content").html(data);
$("#popup-Model").modal();
setTimeout(() => {     
  //change div:first-child to whatever your first child is 
  var width = $("#popup_content div:first-child").width() + 30; //Padding
  $(".modal .modal-dialog").css({ 'width' : width+'px' });
}, 0); //Maybe you'll need a longer timeout because of css transitions
```

[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYqOXx)

Worked in OP case as:

```
$("#popup_content").empty();
var qAjax = new AjaxHelper("/Services/Service.asmx/GetCurrentPopupContent");
qAjax.OnSuccess = function (data) {
$("#popup_content").html('<div class="test-div">' + data + '</div>');
$("#popup-Model").modal();
setTimeout(function () {
    //change div:first-child to whatever your first child is 
    var width = $("#popup_content div:first-child").width() + 50; //padding
    $(".modal-dialog").css({ 'width': width + 'px' });
    $('#popup-Model').css({ 'overflow': 'auto' });
}, 500);
```

Comment: somehow  $("#popup_content:first-child").width(); is returning `null`

Comment: Did you try to put it inside a setTimeout? Also, I think you should do it after calling the `modal` function.I edited my answer.

Comment: yes, I tried it with `SetTimeout` and then posted my comment

Answer (score 0):

add row and col-* class in your popup to handle content

```
<!--Popup Window -->
<div class="modal fade" id="popup-Model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:-10px !important">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="popup_content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!--Popup Window -->
```

Comment: remove all widths from your ajax returned html if you give fix width that will ofcourse go beyond the width or use modal-lg to show large modal

Comment: can you create fiddle where the problem is exists so i can tweak the same fiddle with answer..

Answer (score 0):

try to use **min-width** and **position:relative** style to *"model-body"* class. I hope it will work.